# How to store (or ignore) Base64 images in emails processed by email-to-case?

Tags: email2case, base64

We're getting the following error when receiving an email containing a Base64 encoded image directly in the html:

`Invalid data specified, the provided data does not seem to be a valid image: [B@41eddd5f`

Is there something specific we need to do to handle these types of images in an email?

Comment: Can you please describe steps how to reproduce your bug.
I have html file with image `src='data:image/png;base64,i..`. I'm trying to send it to email-to-case service. Should I see error in case layout? Screenshot will be helpful.

Comment: I can reproduce your bug if additional formatting has been added to image itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following trigger parses case description for base64 images and creates attachments for case.

Email-to-Case functionality stores email body in case description. 
Let's assume we have next html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Base64 image</title>
    <h5>How to store (or ignore) Base64 images in emails processed by email-to-case?</h5>
    </head>
     <body>
     <img style='display:block; ' id='pic1' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAABKUlEQVRYhe1XzQ6CMAwupnsOSFCjz2Hiybf1RGJIeAYPaoxPAole3NwqXcffuPCd6D6ydqVf6ZLicn7DF1mag0IFz9cdYgFt59v13hCxgjABKFS/RetZ43g4OXZZFdA0dRBPM2vbJgBNIiq4Pa79j0RAM1s3tWOj/XJtnWgs+DKLqKavAS6z2g6ugbIqHLsh2fLx9DC2HVwD1GFXnoNTAzH1r7GK7pHAZEDSOYDcKX08tz/+vclAUklfFQV/AkklEs8hOAOSSvp20kT/DWnUfWXFgdsf6cJU4PafXYazB7D0gaUPLH0gqgyzNIdNvnPWgmtgDOdtKkFNcnO7xpB7AQCvEpTm9smnY2luHxNt9w6U5vax4K0B39yuMeReAOCpATn29g278lymP0STAG4R87RyAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC' />
     <img style='display:block; ' id='pic2' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAMSURBVBhXY3growIAAycBLhVrvukAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' />
   </body>
```

*Second image is 1x1px red dot*

In trigger we can use regex to catch all pictures:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z\+/=]{20,} 
or regex with image extension
(?:data:image\/(png|jpeg|gif);base64,)[0-9a-zA-Z\+/=]{20,}
```

After we got our pictures, we can store them as attachments in case:

```
trigger caseTrigger on Case (after insert) {
list <Attachment> attachmentToInsert = new list<Attachment>();
Pattern pngPattern = Pattern.compile('[0-9a-zA-Z\\+/=]{20,}');
for (case cs :trigger.new) {
    Matcher pictures = pngPattern.matcher(cs.description);
    while (pictures.find()) { 
        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
        attach.contentType = 'image/png';
        attach.name = 'emailToCase';
        attach.parentId = cs.id;
        attach.body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(pictures.group());
        attachmentToInsert.add(attach);
    }
}
insert attachmentToInsert;
}
```

If we send HTML specified above to our email to case, we'll got new case and 2 attachments for it:

[image: base64 email to case]

*In the very end I've found that:*

If spaces and new lines has been added for image data - HTML could concatenates it automatically, but email service is adding additional characters. Trigger will create 5 invalid attachment instead of 2.

I think this is your problem, if yes - you should replace spaces and newlines in description e.g. `txt = txt.replaceAll( '\\s+', '').replaceAll( '\\n+', '');`